# Center image in tabularx

Tags: beamer, graphics, tabularx

I am preparing a presentation with `beamer` and I have to make a table with some multi-line cells. So I am using the `tabularx` environment and my code is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}

\newcommand{\tick}{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{img/green-tick}%
}

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.0}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}

\hline
\centering\textbf{Column 1} &
\centering \textbf{Column 2} &
\centering \textbf{Column 3} &
\centering \textbf{Column 4} &
\textbf{Column 5}\\

\hline
Row 1\newline blah &
\tick &
\tick &
\tick & \\

\hline
Row 2 &
\tick &
&
\tick &
\tick\\

\hline
Row 3\newline blah &
\tick &
\tick &
&
\tick\\

\hline
Row 4 & 
&
\tick &
\tick &
\tick\\

\hline
Row 5 &
\tick &
\tick &
\tick &
\tick\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\endgroup
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

What I would like to do is simply to center (both horizontally and vertically) the images in their respective cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `X` column type to use `m` instead of the default `p`, and vertically center the image with a nested `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\tick}{%
  %https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/167549/Kliponious-green-tick.png
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=.5cm]{Kliponious-green-tick.png}
  \end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand{\middlexcolumn}{%
  \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{##1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2.0}
\middlexcolumn
\begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{%
  | *{4}{>{\centering}X|}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}X|
}
\hline
\textbf{Column 1} &
\textbf{Column 2} &
\textbf{Column 3} &
\textbf{Column 4} &
\textbf{Column 5}\\

\hline
Row 1\\ blah &
\tick &
\tick &
\tick & \\

\hline
Row 2 &
\tick &
&
\tick &
\tick\\

\hline
Row 3\newline blah &
\tick &
\tick &
&
\tick\\

\hline
Row 4 & 
&
\tick &
\tick &
\tick\\

\hline
Row 5 &
\tick &
\tick &
\tick &
\tick\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, and I admit I would have never guessed how to do that!